# Create a user defined function that applies conditions to a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a function that checks if any rows in a pandas DataFrame meet a list of conditions. If any are met, I want it to return a 1 to a newly created column called "Error", otherwise, it returns 0.

I created this function to apply the conditions, but it's not working:

```
def validation_error(row):
    """
    Conditions: 

    a. Service Type (col C) == ‘NF’ and Demonstration Type (col D) in ('COST', ‘PERDIEM’) AND
            i. Validation category (col G) == ‘Missing required data’ and Fail column (col L) in (212.1, 212.2) 
    
    b. Service Type (col C) == ‘OP’ and Demonstration Type (col D) == ‘COST’ AND
            i. (Validation category (col G) == ‘Missing required data’ and Fail column (col L)  == 205 OR 
            ii. Validation check (col H) == ‘Data validations: Check selected fields for invalid negative values’ 
            and Fail column (col L) == 205)
        
    c. Issue severity (col I) == ‘Critical - automatic rejection’ 
    """
    # create list of conditions to apply to extract rows
    condition1 = (stacked_df['Issue severity'].str.lower().str.startswith('critical'))
    if row['Service type'] == 'OP':
        condition2 = ((stacked_df['Demonstration type'] == 'PAYMENT') & (stacked_df['Validation category']=='Missing required data') & (stacked_df['Fail column']=='205'))
        condition3 = ((stacked_df['Demonstration type'] == 'PAYMENT') & (stacked_df['Validation check'].str.contains('invalid negative values')) & (stacked_df['Fail column']=='205'))
    elif row['Service type'] == 'NF':
        condition4 = ((stacked_df['Demonstration type'].isin(['COST','PERDIEM'])) & (stacked_df['Validation category']=='Missing required data') & (stacked_df['Fail column'].isin(['212.1','212.2'])))
    return condition1 | condition2 | condition3 | condition4
```

Basically, if the value in the column "Service Type" is equal to OP or NF, I want it to check for the conditions.

I also wrote this additional code that creates the new column and creates a new DataFrame with a column that checks if the conditions were met.

```
# Create a column called 'Error'   
stacked_df['Error'] = stacked_df.apply(validation_error, axis=1)
# Create a new dataframe that meet the conditions list
filtered_df = stacked_df.loc[stacked_dfs['Error'] == 1]
```

How would I include the above code within the "validation_error" function? Also, is there a more elegant way for me to apply the function? Thank you.

Comment: You could apply the function directly to the dataframe and alter it so that it iterates through rows, updates the dataframe accordingly and returns the new "filtered" df.

Answer (score 0):

In your `validation_error()` function you should not reference `stacked_df` but `row` only. Since apply will be applied per row basis.